# Magento Catalog : How to add button or link bellow any field in product add/edit page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, customizable-options

[image]

Like attached screenshot, I want to add Get Next Sku link how to do same does anyone have an idea ? on the same link I want to perform some ajax operation and get some formated SKU but I don't know how to add link bellow SKU textbox.

any help appreciate .. thanks